# JS preventDefault and unbind not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable the links clickable event until the page loads.
But it does not work as expected. Following is my code.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).load(function() {
                 $('a').on("click", function (e) {
                     e.preventDefault();
                 })
             });
         </script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function() {
                 $('a').unbind();
             });

         </script>
```

Comment: what is your requirement actually?

Comment: `$(document).load()` happens after `$(document).ready()` (because `.load()` waits for all of the content to be loaded - css/images, etc, and `.ready()` fires as the DOM is ready). So you are `unbind`ing before you `bind`.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I want to disable the click event on the href links till the page is completely loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).on("click", 'a', function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
         });
     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
             $('a').off("click");
         });

     </script>
```

No need to wait for document to be loaded. Just disable first, then re-enble them  when your document is ready.

Comment: I tried this. But the problem is that unbind doesnt happen... Even after the page is completely loaded the links are still not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in a reverse way to accomplish what you wanted,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //window's load event will be fired after your page loads all resources
  $(window).load(function() {
     //Turn off the bound click event to the anchor tags.
     $('a').off("click");
  });
  //prevent the click over anchor tags.
  $('a').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```